# Dynamically add ext.menu.Menu to ext.panel.Panel

Tags: extjs, menu, panel, menuitem

I dynamically create several panels and add the into an accordion menu. For each of this panels I want to add an `ext.menu.Menu` component but when I try do that the menu is not visible and also not present in the DOM. I also create a few menu items which I add to the menu.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < store.totalCount; ++i){

       var rec = store.getAt(i);

        var panelItem =  new Ext.panel.Panel({
            title: (Ext.Date.format(rec.data.dateBorn, 'd-m-Y')) + " " + rec.data.name,
            value:rec.data.VALUE_FIELD,
        });

        panel.add(panelItem);

       var userMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        className:"menu"
    });  

       panelItem.add(userMenu);
}
```

If I create a menu item and add to the panel it is shown, but I want to have them in a menu, What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu is by default floating component. To configure component as floating or not floating you can use `floating` configuration property.

So if you want to display menu directly in your panel the configuration of menu should be:

```
  var userMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
    width: 120,
    height: 70,        
    className:"menu",
    floating: false,
});
```